# CloudKit iOS 10 Error: Account doesn't have access to CloudKit account

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, ios10

For some reason, a small subset of my users on iOS 10 are unable to read from my public iCloud container.

The localisedError that CloudKit returns is "Account doesn't have access to CloudKit account", however after searching online, I can't find any mention of this error.

Does anyone have any ideas what would cause this? Example code sample below.

```
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor.init(key: "Version", ascending: false)
let publicDatabase = CKContainer(identifier:"iCloud.blah.blah.blah").publicCloudDatabase
let truePredicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
let VersionQuery = CKQuery(recordType: "Version", predicate: truePredicate)

VersionQuery.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

publicDatabase.performQuery(VersionQuery, inZoneWithID: nil) { (record, error) -> Void in
        print("Cloudkit Error = \(error?.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Comment: Same thing here. CF: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/64412 Which looks like your same question. I started having the issue on iOS 10.1 beta, for what it's worth.

Comment: I'm getting reports of the same problem - reportedly with users who are *not* on the beta, too.

Answer (score 2):

I too am having this issue. It seems that users that have their iCloud Drive OFF (running iOS 10) can't access data in the public container. As soon as they enable iCloud Drive, then they can access the public container again. I'm not sure why this is happening and have submitted a bug report.